# Django models group-by related

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, distinct

I am using Django 1.4 with MySQL. I have the following models:

```
Event:
    title = CharField()
    description = CharField()


Dates:
   event = ForeignKey(Event)
   location = ForeignKey(Location)
   date = DateTimeField()
   participants = IntegerField()

Location:
   ........
```

I need to select the first available date for each event ( and the location ) where the participants number is bigger than X

In MySQL query it's just a select on Date table with joins for event and location grouped by event. But this is not possible in Django and distinct("field") is not supported by MySQL

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is as follows:

```
event_dates = Dates.objects.filter(participants__gte=200
    ).values('event').annotate(Max('date'))
```

Which would translate to a MYSQL of

```
SELECT MAX(date) FROM dates GROUP BY event WHERE participants > 200;
```

Then you would access it as

```
for event_date in event_dates:
    print event_date.0
```